# Можно ли писать на TypeScript под NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Вопрос о том, хорошая ли это практика? Смогу ли я использовать без особых проблем пакеты из npm, либо какие-то сторонние скрипты/классы написанные на js?
Нужны все плюсы и минусы этого подхода, хочется знать, стоит ли начинать nodejs-проект на ts, или же ограничиться es6.

p.s. Я читал что в ts 1.8 есть какая-то штука которая без особых усилий адаптирует любой код, но незнаю насколько это эффективно

Answer (score 4):

Есть дефинишены для typescript: https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions

Но обновлялась она давно, как сейчас дела, не знаю, поддержка может хварать. А это значит, что в конце концов вы можете упереться в проблему и придется допиливать декларации. Я бы не рекомендовал использовать это.

Помимо этого есть проблемы с тем что TypeScript, как и другие трансляторы, фреймворки и библиотеки - специфичны: не все их знают, не все проблемы известны и некоторые нестандартные задачи приводят вас к тому, что приходится разбираться, а иногда и менять внутренности этих систем.

Comment: спасибо) я кстати читал что в ts 1.8 есть какая-то штука которая без особых усилий адаптирует любой код, но не знаю насколько это эффективно

Comment: Тут сказать ничего не могу, работал я с ним год назад, возможно это действительно сейчас не проблема. Но остается одна вещь: веб развивается очень бурно - любая технология популярная сегодня - завтра уже не актуальна. Если библиотеку можно выпилить, то в вашем случае это может вылиться в переписывание проекта.

Comment: @AleksanderK. не надо так пугать. Если потом придется отказаться от TypeScript - то это можно будет делать не сразу, а помодульно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну в общем то да, но все равно переписывать) Хотя да, должен признаться, что код результата трансляции вполне читаемый.

Comment: проще говоря пиши на js